# QPushButton aligment to the topright corner

Tags: qt

I've 3 QFrame in the mainwindow, the frames looks like this:

[image: pic]

I'd like to set a 60x20 QPushButton to the **QFram I** top right corner. I also resize the window and the frames resizes with the window.

I don't want to resize the push button, when the window resize.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    window = new QWidget;
    frame1 = new QFrame(window);
    frame2 = new QFrame(window);
    frame3 = new QFrame(window);
    
    //check purpose
    frame1->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
    frame2->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);
    frame3->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box);

    button = new QPushButton(frame1);
    button->resize(60,20);


    setCentralWidget(window);
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e) {
    window->resize(e->size());
    frame1->setGeometry(0, 0, e->size().width() * 0.5, e->size().height() * 0.4);
    frame2->setGeometry(0, e->size().height() * 0.4, e->size().width() * 0.5, e->size().height() * 0.6);
    frame3->setGeometry(e->size().width() * 0.5, 0, e->size().width() * 0.5, e->size().height());
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.  Also have a look at [using layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @G.M. I have just added the code

Comment: I know abour layout, I just want to add the button to the frame1 top right corner, I do not want to resize the button when the window resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `button` is the `QPushButton` you want to appear in the top right of `frame` you can probably use something like the following (untested)...

```
button = new QPushButton(frame1);
button->setFixedSize(60,20);
button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

auto *layout = new QGridLayout(frame1);
layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
layout->setMargin(0);
layout->setSpacing(0);
layout->addWidget(button, 0, 1);
layout->setRowStretch(1, 1);
layout->setColumnStretch(0, 1);
```

Note the use of `QWidget::setFixedSize` rather than `QWidget::resize`.

Comment: There is another problem as well, as I mentioned in my question, I'd like to keep the push button size 60x20,     `button = new QPushButton(frame1);      button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed));    button->resize(60,20);`, but the size of the push button is not 60x20

Comment: @ekato Updated the answer to use `setFixedSize` rather than `resize`.  A quick test suggests it should do what I think you're after.

Comment: I've read through [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html), but I cannot figure out who could I position another pushbutton to the bottom right corner. Maybe this should be another question, but I think this is better to ask here.

Comment: @ekato Please ask a separate question.

Comment: I have asked another question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648191/qpushbutton-aligment-to-the-bottom-right-corner)